# Two type relationship - problem with append attribute

Tags: php, laravel, backend, relationship

I have a 2 type of relationship between 2 models. Look at the code

```
protected $appends = [
    'avatar_name'

];
public function avatar() {
    return $this->hasOne(Avatar::class)->latest();
}

public function avatars()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Avatar');
}
public function getAvatarNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['avatar_name'] = isset($this->avatar->name) ? $this->avatar->name : null;
}
```

Into Profile model I have only one relationship:

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
}
```

This relationships is clear for me - I need display all avatars for single profile (which he upload) and display one avatar which will be display in navigation or in a comments. Problem is that if I try to change the avatar, avatar_name displays all the time this same value. Profile models have `avatar_id` field, of course.

@Update

I try check that in tinker, so I wrote

```
Profile::with('avatar')->find(1)->latest()->first()
```

But all the time it display this same avatar_name

Answer (score 0):

In Migration (Avatars):

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
```

In Profile Model:

```
public function avatars()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Avatar');
}
```

In  Controller:

```
$profile = Profile::with('avatars')->find($id);
$avatar = $profile->avatars()->latest()->first();
$avatars = $profile->avatars()->latest()->get();
```

Output will return like this (Avatar is first and Avatars array is second):
[image: Avatar and Avatars]

Note: As you can see in example image latest() by default sorts by ID not date time for this you have to specify table (idk why one would do that but in case).

Comment: it desn't work. If I use `latest()` in hasOne relationship, it always display the latest uploaded avatar. If i remove that it display first. I remove`->latest` from avatars (hasMany) but it nothining change.

Comment: try this updated code and if not resolved add your models for more info.

Comment: @wtsuport $user = User::with('avatars')->find(3);
        $data = $user->avatars()->latest()->first();

Comment: updated code as well give it a try.

Comment: It doesn't work. All the time it's display this same avatar - first or latest, denf's of query. But in controller I want to write `Profile::findOrFail($id)` and I want to have `avatar_name`

Comment: Can you tell if you get one part right atleast where you want to get all the users avatar? And if you want user to select a specific image to be profile picture (among the uploaded) just add a table field as isAvatar (set true if user selects it else defaults to false)

Comment: All in all, you're right. Tomorrow, I'll try do that :)